# What would cause my truck to shut off during me cranking it?

Tags: battery, starting, mercury

My 1999 Mercury Mountaineer shut off during mid crank. It acted as if it wanted to crank then it shut off. Everything shut down. Outside and inside lights shut off. When I tried to crank it, it didn't say or do anything. So I tried jumping it off and it charged a little bit but not enough for it to crank. It made a ticking sound while I was turning the switch but that's all it did. I waited a little while to see if it would charge but it never charged enough to crank. What could be my problem?

Answer (score 4):

I'm just spit balling here but it may be possible battery's life has come to an end. Cranking a vehicle draws a lot of current from the battery acting as a big straw that sucks current away from other components (ECU and dashboard). I would first proceed by changing the car battery.

This depends on if the vehicle failed to start first time ^

The other possibility is some vehicles have a safety feature that shuts the vehicle down if it has failed to start a number of times. So if the vehicle was repeatedly cranking this may have kicked in. this safety feature disengages after around 10 15 minutes (possibly more depending on vehicle).

Assuming after you charged the vehicle the lights came back on (safety feature disengaged) could you have possibly burnt the starter motor out? Or could it possibly be jammed?

^ This would depend on the vehicle failing to start Repeatedly

I’m sure some other person with more experience will be along shortly with what could possibly be a common fault of the vehicle.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though either its a bad battery or the battery has lost connection. Your best bet is to take the battery out of your vehicle and charge it. If it comes up to full charge, put it back into the vehicle and see if that does the trick. If it won't charge, take it to an auto parts store and have them load test it. They can tell you if it's bad or not.